# HTML tags and attributes defect client from receiving email using SmtpClient via anonymous account

Tags: c#, outlook, smtp

I am cracking my head to find a solution for that strange behavior.
I have made a lot of tests and experiments and tried to play around with my code but with no success.

**Server**: Windows service on windows server 2012 .net framework 4.0.

**Client:** windows 7 os, outlook 2010.

**Problem:** html tags and \ or attributes inside the message body are affecting client from receiving emails and no exception is thrown on the server.
there are several cases that html inside the body message is preventing from the client to receive email to his outlook inbox.

**Example:** if i am calling `SendHtmlEmail()` like that everything works fine as expected:

```
Exchange.InvokeEmail.SendHtmlEmail("testTrue", "<div dir=rtl><br/>test</div>", "jonathana@xxx.net",null, "מערכת ניהול פרויקטים", null,true);
```

but if i am removing the `<br/>` tag, the client is not receiving email and **no** exception is thrown:

```
Exchange.InvokeEmail.SendHtmlEmail("testTrue", "<div dir=rtl> test</div>", "jonathana@xxx.net",null, "מערכת ניהול פרויקטים", null,true);
```

another example is using the `dir` attribute:

```
"<body dir=rtl> test </body>" // not working
"<body ><br/>test</body>" // working
"<div dir=rtl> test </div>" // not working
"<div ><br/>test</div>" // working
```

I have tried to change Encoding of the body but nothing helps.
 also, because no exception is raised I assume the problem is on client side(?) (outlook 2010, windows 7 os).

Thank you.

**Server code:**

```
public static bool SendHtmlEmail(string _subject, string _body,
    string _to, string _cc = null,
    string _DisplayName = "מערכת ניהול פרויקטים", string _FileName = null,bool Isanonymous = true)
{
    try
    {

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        // from
        if (Isanonymous == false)
            msg.From = new MailAddress("pmsapp@partner.co.il");
        else
            msg.From = new MailAddress("PmsApplication@partner.co.il", _DisplayName);

        // to
        foreach (var address in _to.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            msg.To.Add(address);
        }

        // cc
        if (_cc != null && _cc.Contains("@"))
        {
            foreach (var address in _cc.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                msg.CC.Add(address);
            }
        }

        msg.Subject = _subject;
        msg.Body = _body;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        if (Isanonymous==false)
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx", "xxxxxxx");

        client.Port = 25;
        client.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Exchange.SmtpServerName"];
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        client.Send(msg);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = ex.ToString(); // TODO: write to database
        return false;
    }
}
```